# I can't make my Ubuntu 18.04 hibernate (I tried use both swap file and swap partion, nothing works)

Tags: suspend, swap, 18.04, hibernate, pm-utils

As the title suggest.

I've already tried `sudo pm-hibernate`, `sudo systemctl hibernate`, `sudo s2disk` all of them did nothing and just freeze on input in the terminal, except `sudo systemctl hibernate` which seems to shutdown the system instantly but fail to resume after start the machine back up again.

I had 8 Gb RAM, 9 Gb Swap partition, when I first tried and I've already added `resume` parameter in `/etc/default/grub`. And failed after I tried to hibernate as I described above.

After that I tried use swap file instead of swap partition to hibernate by creating a 5 Gb swap file (I heard that I only need at least half the size of my RAM) and then add the parameter `resume_offset` to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` the same way as I did with `resume`.

I also add the following to `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla`

```
[Re-enable hibernate by default in upower]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
ResultActive=yes

[Re-enable hibernate by default in logind]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate
ResultActive=yes
```

and also edit the following (changing from `yes` to `no` in the `ResultActive` both section) in `/var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/10-vendor.d/com.ubuntu.desktop.pkla`:

```
[Disable hibernate by default in upower]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
ResultActive=no

[Disable hibernate by default in logind]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate;org.freedesktop.login1.handle-hibernate-key;org.freedesktop.login1;org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-multiple-sessions;org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-ignore-inhibit
ResultActive=no
```

Note that when I use `sudo pm-hibernate` I only have `pm-utils` installed.
And when I used `sudo s2disk` I uninstall `pm-utils` before reinstall `uswsusp` then run the command like this

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure -pmedium uswsusp
```

before `sudo s2disk` and then again nothings happened

what did I do wrong? I don't know what else I should try.

Comment: Ok, sorry.  I'm a bit desperate.

Comment: Take a look at this page: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingKernelHibernate and https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Reference/S4#Machine_Boot_Failure

Comment: This blog is also an excellent one: https://01.org/blogs/rzhang/2015/best-practice-debug-linux-suspend/hibernate-issues

Answer (score 1):

Look at your `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume` file. It should contain the UUID of your swap partition, like so:

`RESUME=UUID=071f8b0e-8e16-4f4d-90ff-a4ae9cc56e2b` # use your own correct UUID

To identify the correct UUID to use:

`sudo blkid` # to display your UUIDs

Look for a line similar to this:

`/dev/sda8: UUID="071f8b0e-8e16-4f4d-90ff-a4ae9cc56e2b" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="d042d9f3-dfe7-4ba9-bbc8-efe6413e7fa4"` # your UUID will be different

Then perform:

`sudo update-initramfs -c` # to create a fresh initramfs image file

`reboot` # to reboot the computer

Now retest hibernate.

Comment: Ok now there's `RESUME=UUID=592d80c6-6112-4602-95f7-47f80d67e0e8`, which is the UUID of my swap partition in my `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume` 

Then I ran `sudo update-initramfs -c -k 4.15.0-20-generic` then reboot and test hibernation with `sudo systemctl hibernate` (with `uswsusp` and `pm-utils` purged)

..well it didn't hibernate but it turns into the Screen Lock instead

Comment: @AidenBhe did hibernate work in 17.10? From your update-initramfs command, you're running kernel 4.15.0-20-generic, yes? Hibernate is normally disabled in Ubuntu for operational reliability issues, and may never work on your computer. However, have you checked for a BIOS update?

Comment: @AidenBhe you may have to edit /etc/default/grub and find the `quiet splash` line and add something like `resume=/dev/sda8` or `resume=UUID=592d80c6-6112-4602-95f7-47f80d67e0e8` and then `sudo update-grub`, reboot and retest.

Comment: Thank you for a quick reply. I've already done that here's the lines in `/etc/default/grub`

    `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash resume=UUID=592d80c6-6112-4602-95f7-47f80d67e0e8"`
    `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""`

and yes `4.15.0-20-generic` is my kernel version. I haven't thought about flashing BIOS though I'll try that and let you know!

Comment: And also I just returned to Ubuntu recently so I haven't use 17.04 or 17.10 before.

Comment: It works for me, but the wired network is always down after restore, and I cant make it up until restart.

Answer (score 0):

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="resume=UUID=959b6..."
```

in `/etc/default/grub` did this for me on xubuntu 18.04 after grup update and install. You see it resuming on boot.
But when I use

```
sudo systemctl hibernate
```

resuming fails. With hibernate by window manager it works. I patched `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla` as described to enable hibernation. I did not install pm-utils or uswsusp.

Comment: By "window manager" did you mean from GNOME? Because from my desktop I don't have any Hibernation Button in the status menu when I recently installed Ubuntu 18.04. But I did add a GNOME extension to have the button in the status menu though and it did the same thing when I  `sudo systemctl hibernate`

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem in Ubuntu 18.04.  Found that it was necessary to update the kernel.

The s2disk resume did not work for me in 4.15.0.

It is working for me in 4.18.12.