# Ubuntu 22.04 crashes on suspend/wakeup

Tags: nvidia, 22.04, suspend

- Around 4 days ago I performed the suggested software updates and since then **my notebook crashes on wake up**, please help me debugging and solving it.

  - Right now, when I wake up the notebook I see a black screen with what I believe are logs from the kernel
  - The only option forward is a power cycle by pressing and holding the power button
  - I followed the steps suggested in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/280843/1737743) for restoring the state of before the update, but the problem persists.
- The problem seems related to nvidia drivers but I can't say for sure.
- Find below information about the error itself and about my system.

#### Information about the error itself

- This is the first messages I see when I wakeup the system:

```bash
[ 9839.255865] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00. 1: Unable to change power state from D3cold to DO, device Inaccessible
[ 9840.789274] snd_hda_codec_hdmi hdaudioC1D0: Unable to sync register 0x7f0800. -5
[ 9842.206773] Bluetooth: hci0: Malformed MSFT vendor event: Ox02
[ 9842.513179] mei_me 0000:00:16.0: hbm: pg entry response: state mismatch [OFF, 0]
[ 9842.513195] mei_me 0000:00:16.0: mei_irq_read_handler ret = -71, state = 2.
```

- Then a lot of new entries show up really quickly and it stops in the following  [beautiful picture of a black screen](https://imgur.com/a/6RACUCi)

#### Information about my system:

- This is my Notebook:

```
Notebook Acer Aspire Nitro 5 AN515-52-72UU Intel® Core™ i7-8750H RAM de 16GB SSD de 128GB HD de 1TB GeForce® GTX 1050Ti 4GB 15.6” FHD Windows10
```

- This is my ubuntu:

```
ggm@ggm-nitro5:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
ggm@ggm-nitro5:~$ uname -r
6.2.0-34-generic
```

- Tell me what other information I can provide.

Comment: It looks like your sound card doesn't survive the suspend/wake-up. Check [this thread](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/unable-to-disable-snd-hda-intel-power-save-through-modprobe/31568/6) on how to disable the sound module. (just to verify it is that module)

Comment: @kanehekili THanks for the reply. I was able to blacklist the `snd_hda_intel` module. I restarted the machine and confirmed that it was not loaded. Unfortunatelly the problem still exists, the only difference is that now the first line that shows up is `Bluetooth: hci0: Malformed MSFT vendor event: 0x02` instead of the snd_hda_intel line....

Is there a way I can fetch these logs after I power cycle my machine?

Comment: `journalctl -b -1` (or -2...) will show you the logs from boot -1. To find errors you might need some more switches like -x -e.  See also my [related answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1104094/906933) - use the barebone kernel commands to find out which driver fails.

Comment: same problem here, Acer Aspire A715-71G, downgraded Nvidia driver from 535 to 470 for trooubleshooting, no change

Comment: Same problem. Acer Nitro 5, Lubuntu 22.04.3 LTS x86_64, NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Ti Mobile, NVIDIA driver 470.199.02. Problem started for me after updating kernel to 6.2.0-35. Current workaround for me is to boot with 6.2.0-32 kernel.